# How can I use .in and .sol files?

Tags: testing

What do I even do with those? I need to use the .in ones as an input for my program and I guess the .sol ones contain the expected solution.

Answer (score 0):

If no other input/output conventions have been made clear to you, then my guess is that the .in and .sol files can be treated as text files with file extensions used as a method of distinction.

In other words:

Open the .in file as input using the appropriate methods of the programming language you're using as though it were a .txt file. When providing the output, write the output to a file using the .sol file extension.